# null is not an object (evaluating 'RCTToastAndroid.SHORT')

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I am attempting to convert my react-native project into an expo project, one small issue I've encountered is when I run the expo project I get an error as such

`null is not an object (evaluating 'RCTToastAndroid.SHORT')`

After doing some research online on how to fix this problem a user requested that a problem like this can simply be resolved by removing the `Android` part of `RCTToastAndroid.SHORT` this user stated that `RCTToast` is universally compatible with both iOS and Android. However when I do this I receive an error saying `null is not an object (evaluating 'RCTToast.SHORT')`

What can I do that will help ease the transition from my react-native project to an expo project?

Comment: Hi I'm getting a SIMILAR error...but not RCTToastAndroid.SHORT but just RCTToast.SHORT.  Full error is => TypeError: null is not an object (evaulating 'RCTToast.SHORT'). Any idea how to fix? Note: Mine is only RCTToast and not RCTToastAndroid.

Answer (score 1):

All apps created with create-react-native-app, are compatible with Expo CLI without changes.

Ref link:- https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#upgrading-from-1140-to-201

Comment: I edited my `app.json` file to make it runable by expo. So that works, however when I publish my project I run into a new error `Unhandled JS Exception: null is not an object (evaluating 't.SHORT')`

Answer (score 1):

only do like this

```js
import {ToastAndroid}from 'react-native '
return ToastAndroid.show("some error msg", ToastAndroid.LONG);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, when I publish my project in expo I get the error `Unhandled JS Exception: null is not an object (evaluating 't.SHORT')` do you have any advice?

Comment: in expo my be different my friend you can find it in documentation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem.

Check to see if you've imported a library called **'react-native-simple-toast'**. Remove it from your dependencies.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/vonovak/react-native-simple-toast/issues/7):

> this library has a custom native module for ios, and expo does not support that.  This lib will not work with expo

it will only work with a bare React Native project.

---

### If you do need to use Toasts

[Here's a library](https://github.com/magicismight/react-native-root-toast) that will work with Expo on both Android and iOS. The only downside is that it's pure Javascript.

You can use it like this:

```js
import Toast from 'react-native-root-toast'

Toast.show('Your message here', {
    duration: Toast.durations.SHORT,
    position: Toast.positions.BOTTOM,
    shadow: true,
    animation: true
});
```